# Grouping QS, getting min and max values and disregard entries in between in resulting QS

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have following, very simple model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('A', u'Alfa-event'),
        ('B', u'Beta-event'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Following entries are created for this model:

```
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-01-23")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-01-30")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-02-03")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-02-05")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-02-06")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-02-25")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-03-21")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-04-28")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-07-05")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-07-06")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-07-07")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-07-20")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-08-01")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-09-01")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-09-03")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-09-15")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="B", date="2015-09-16")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-10-01")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-10-14")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-10-20")
>>> Event.objects.create(type="A", date="2015-10-31")
```

In a view, I would like to achieve following table (preferably through a `Queryset` so I can use its advantages):

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
|   Type    |    From    |     To     |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| Alfa-type | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-31 |
| Beta-type | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-16 |
| Alfa-type | 2015-07-05 | 2015-08-01 |
| Beta-type | 2015-01-23 | 2015-04-28 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Basically it groups all `Event`s per type, and "remembers" the from and to date, after which it is shown in the result/table. All the events of the same type in between are not part of the result.

The `from` date can be achieved as the min of the event dates that have the same consecutive event type. The `to` date as the max of these event dates. Again, the events in between should not be shown.

This seems like an easy problem, but I've been breaking my head over this during the past days.

- I tried looking at aggregation, but that didn't help me since I had all my A or B type events grouped together and hence only showing up once in the resulting table.
- Also I looked at going over the QuerySet Events.objects.all() manually but I'm stuck there.

Would anyone know how to best approach this?

Using Django 1.8 on Python 2.7 and Postgres.

Thanks!

**Edit**:

I came up with the below solution. It works, but I find it a bit of hacking around. If there would be anyone with improvements to this, I'd be happy to hear them.

```
qs = Event.objects.all().order_by('-date')

event_from_ids = []
event_to_ids = []
event_to_ids.append(qs.first().id)

for current_event, next_event in zip(qs, qs[1:]):
    #print "current id:", current_event.id, " next id:", next_event.id
    if current_event.type != next_event.type:
        event_from_ids.append(current_event.id)
        event_to_ids.append(next_event.id)
event_from_ids.append(qs.last().id)

resulting_qs = qs.filter(id__in=event_from_ids)

# Using enumerate to keep track of the index while going over the loop
for idx, val in enumerate(resulting_qs):
    val.to_date = Event.objects.get(pk=event_to_ids[idx]).date
```

When executing following code (similar to what one would do in a view):

```
for event in resulting_qs:
    print "Event type: ", event.type, " from: ", event.date, " to: ", event.to_date
```

... following table is returned:

```
Event type:  A  from:  2015-10-01  to:  2015-10-31
Event type:  B  from:  2015-09-01  to:  2015-09-16
Event type:  A  from:  2015-07-05  to:  2015-08-01
Event type:  B  from:  2015-01-23  to:  2015-04-28
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as you should have your start date and end date stored in your DB so you don't need to group the query based on your event types.

technically something like this should work if your DB is correctly designed.

view.py

```
mydate = datetime.now() #or whatever date you need
events = event.objects.filter(date__lt=mydate, date__gt=mydate
    ).order_by('date')[:10]
```

template.html

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{ event.type }} | {{ event.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. 
First off, the query you made will never return a result since you're filtering on both LT and GT (which cannot be true at the same time). When changing to LTE/GTE, some result might be returned, but only for one particular `mydate`. 
I'm looking for the overall overview. 
Also, I'm not sure what you mean with `if your DB is correctly designed`: my model is posted in my opening post (?).